# How to use FIND_IN_SET in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, find, set

How to use FIND_IN_SET,

The values I have is

```
|       Val         |
| No, 1, Yes,5, O, 4|
```

I tried doing

```
FIND_IN_SET('No', Val)
```

And got the value of `1` and then I tried:

```
FIND_IN_SET('No', Val) as 'No', FIND_IN_SET('Yes', Val) as ''Yes'
```

But got the output

```
|   No  |   Yes |
|   1   |   0   |
```

How come it suddenly can't find the 'Yes' in the text?

Another format:

```
| Val   |
| No, 1, 
  Yes,5, 
  O, 4   |
```

Note: This is not on 3 rows, just on one row but using the next line(line breaks) for the other values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the actual value in your string is `' Yes'`  (with a space)

This will work

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(' Yes',Val) FROM test
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccc68f/2)**

But then it wont work if `Yes` is the first value without space. You can do this for a general case scenario (a little expensive though)

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('Yes',REPLACE(Val," ","")) FROM test
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccc68f/4)**

Comment: ahh i see. thank you! just one more question, i just want to clarify that the 'FIND_IN_SET' it finds the position of the string right?

Comment: How come it doesn't work when the text is like `No, 1, ` then the next text will be on the next line `Yes,5,`? please see update

Comment: Because of the newline character, replace that as wel

Answer (score 0):

Because `'Yes'` is not in that set. However, `' Yes'` is.

Run:

```
SET @foo = 'No, 1, Yes,5, O, 4';
SELECT
  FIND_IN_SET('No', @foo),
  FIND_IN_SET('Yes', @foo),
  FIND_IN_SET(' Yes', @foo);
```

Result set: `1,0,3`

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the position of the string.
You can easily understand the use of FIND_IN_SET with this tutorial -

http://phpforweb.info/how-to-use-find_in_set-in-mysql-query/